# Laravel5 Eloquent model not hiding json values

Tags: json, laravel-5, eloquent

My contacts model is not hiding fields. This worked in Laravel4 with no problems, so did something change? am i doing it wrong?

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = ['confirmation_code', 'confirmed', 'status'];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

I have even tried the reverse by only allowing certain fields

```
    protected $visible = ['lName', 'fName', 'company', 'phone']
```

Could the problem be that my Contacts model is using the same table as my Users model? If thats the case. Whats the right way to have 2 models use the same table?

Answer (score 0):

I missed the fact that i had 2 different contact models... in different namespaces.. I was referencing the wrong namespace. So everything is working like it should. It was all me not paying attention.